# How to use a connected-to-Redux-Higher-Order-Component inside a Component which is also connected to Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to wrap a `Container` which uses `Redux` with a `HOC`, which also uses `Redux`, taking me to the following error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> 112 | export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withRouter(withError(VeggieBuilder)))
```

I have been trying to figure it out on my own and I guess that the solution has something to do with the use of `compose` from `redux` when exporting either my `HOC` or my `Container`.

I will post the whole `HOC` here and just the `container's` exporting part right below the `HOC` block.

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
import Modal from "../../UI/Modal/Modal";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actionCreators from  '../../../store/actions/indexActions'

const withError = WrappedComponent => {
    return props => {
        return<Fragment>
            <Modal show={props.error} modalCanceled={() => props.onResetError()}>
                {props.error && props.error}
            </Modal>
            <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </Fragment>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        error: state.httpReqReducer.errorMessage
    }
}

const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onResetError: () => dispatch(actionCreators.resetError())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(withError)
```

now the `export` part of my `Container` called `VeggieBuilder`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withRouter(withError(VeggieBuilder)))
```

If remove the `connection` with `Redux` on the `export` of my `HOC` the error disappears.

Thanks in advance to all.

If any additional info is needed here, I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your HOC this way:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Modal from "../../UI/Modal/Modal";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actionCreators from '../../../store/actions/indexActions'

const withError = WrappedComponent => {
  const wrappedComp = props => {
    return <Fragment>
      <Modal show={props.error} modalCanceled={() => props.onResetError()}>
        {props.error && props.error}
      </Modal>
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    </Fragment>
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      error: state.httpReqReducer.errorMessage
    }
  }

  const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onResetError: () => dispatch(actionCreators.resetError())
    }
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(wrappedComp);
}

export default withError;
```

Calling `connect` with `mapState` and `mapDispatch` will return a function that expects a react component as an argument.

So when you use `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(withError)` note that `withError` is not a react component but instead it's a function that returns a react component.

Comment: incredible! Thanks for the insight. It worked perfectly well. I will surely keep this lesson learned in mind for the future